# CakePHP 1.3 or 2.0.0-RC2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to start developing in an MVC framework, specifically CakePHP.

I see they have released 2.0.0-RC2 and was wondering if it is a waste of time to start an app in 1.3 when 2.0 is right around the corner. Should I start learning and developing in 2.0-RC2 rather as I'm guessing most of what I will learn in 1.3 now might become redundant soon?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against starting on a Release Candidate when you are new to the platform or programming pattern - mostly because you won't know the difference between broken/missing functionality and your lack of knowledge.

Start with the stable build, then move to the new hotness once it has an official release.

Comment: Thanks for the quick, efficient reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can start learning CakePHP 1.3. There is official [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/) from where you can start and also you have a lot of examples on internet. When CakePHP 2.0 come stable you will be ready to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well .. first of all , i would recommend against use of php frameworks before you have learned enough to understand how they work.

But especially large distance should be kept from Cake and other Ruby on Rails clones in PHP. They all are filled with bad practices, and it is **not** MVC pattern which they are implementing.

Comment: What is it that they're implementing then?

Comment: @Ivo , the closest architecture would be [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter).

Answer (score 0):

I would start with CakePHP 2.0.0-RC2 as CakePHP 2.0 is the future of CakePHP. CakePHP 1.3.x is outdated in my opinion as it is still PHP4-based...

For documentation, see the cookbook for CakePHP 2.0: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/ . And if there are questions, ask in the IRC channel, or post in the Google group (or here), and/or read the source code.